# Form Submission Issue - Next.JS and PrismaDB

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I'm currently facing an issue with submitting a form in my application and would greatly appreciate some assistance in troubleshooting it.

**Problem:**

The form in my application is not submitting successfully. Despite ensuring that all required fields are filled out, I'm encountering errors when attempting to submit it.

**Errors:**

1. One of the errors I'm encountering is: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'styles' does not exist in type '(Without<SubCategoryUpdateManyMutationInput, SubCategoryUncheckedUpdateManyInput> & SubCategoryUncheckedUpdateManyInput) | (Without<...> & SubCategoryUpdateManyMutationInput)'.`
2. Additionally, I'm receiving a validation error related to the missing `store_id` argument, even though the store definitely exists and is correctly identified in the browser URL.

**Related Code:**

Here are the relevant code snippets and API routes:

**1. Form Component:**

```
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import * as z from "zod";


interface SubCategoryFormProps {
 initialData: SubCategory | null;
 categories: Category[];
}


const formSchema = z.object({
 name: z.string().min(1),
 category_id: z.string().min(1),
 style: z.string(),
});


type SubCategoryFormValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema> ;


const SubCategoryForm: React.FC<SubCategoryFormProps> = ({
 initialData,
 categories,
}) => {
 const params = useParams();
 const router = useRouter();
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 const [saveStyle, setSaveStyle] = useState<{ name: string }[]>([]);
 const [styleModalOpen, setStyleModalOpen] = useState(false);
 const [alertModalOpen, setAlertModalOpen] = useState(false);


 const title = initialData ? "Edit Sub-Category" : "Create Sub-Category";
 const description = initialData ? "Edit a Sub-Category" : "Add a New Sub-Category";
 const toastSubMessage = initialData ? "Sub-Category Updated!" : "Sub-Category Created!";
 const action = initialData ? "Save Changes" : "Create";
  const form = useForm<SubCategoryFormValues>({
   resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
   defaultValues: initialData ?? {
     name: "",
     category_id: "",
     style: "",
   },
 });


  const addStyle = () => {
   const styleValue = form.getValues("style");
   if (styleValue) {
     setSaveStyle((prev) => [...prev, { name: styleValue }]);
     form.setValue("style", "");
   }
 };


 const removeStyle = (index: number) => {
   setSaveStyle((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
 };


 const onSubmit = async (data: SubCategoryFormValues) => {
   const styles = saveStyle.map((styles) => styles.name);
   const { style, ...formData } = data;
   const productData = {
     ...formData,
     styles
   };
   try {
     console.log(productData)
     setLoading(true);
     if (initialData) {
       await axios.patch(
         `/api/${params.store_id}/sub-categories/${params.subcategory_id}`,
         productData
       );
     } else {
       await axios.post(`/api/${params.store_id}/sub-categories`, productData);
     }
     router.refresh();
     router.push(`/${params.store_id}/sub-categories`);
     toast.success(toastSubMessage);
   } catch (error) {
     console.error("API Error:", error);
     if (error.response) {
       console.error("API Error Response:", error.response.data);
     }
     toast.error("Something Went Wrong");
   } finally {
     setLoading(false);
   }
 };


 const onDelete = async () => {
   try {
     setLoading(true);
     await axios.delete(
       `/api/${params.store_id}/sub-categories/${params.subcategory_id}`
     );
     router.refresh();
     router.push(`/${params.store_id}/sub-categories`);
     toast.success("Sub-Category Deleted.");
   } catch (error) {
     toast.error(
       "Make Sure You Have Removed All Styles Using This Sub-Category First."
     );
   } finally {
     setLoading(false);
     setOpen(false);
   }
 };


 return (
   <>
     <AlertModal
       isOpen={open}
       onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
       onConfirm={onDelete}
       loading={loading}
     />
     <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
       <Heading title={title} description={description} />
       {initialData && (
         <Button
           variant="destructive"
           size="sm"
           onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
           disabled={loading}
         >
           <Trash className="h-4 w-4" />
         </Button>
       )}
     </div>
     <Separator />
     <Form {...form}>
       <form
         onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
         className="space-y-8 w-full"
       >
         <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8">
         ...
           <FormField
             control={form.control}
             name="name"
             render={({ field }) => (
               <FormItem>
                 <FormLabel>Sub-Category Name</FormLabel>
                 <FormControl>
                   <Input
                     disabled={loading}
                     placeholder="E.g. Shoes"
                     {...field}
                   />
                 </FormControl>
                 <FormMessage />
               </FormItem>
             )}
           />
           <FormField
             control={form.control}
             name="style"
             render={({ field }) => (
               <FormItem>
                 <FormLabel>Style Name(s)</FormLabel>
                 <FormControl>
                   <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
                     <Input
                       disabled={loading}
                       placeholder="E.g. Trainers"
                       {...field}
                     />
                     <Button
                       type="button"
                       size="sm"
                       onClick={addStyle}
                     >
                       <Plus className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                       Add
                     </Button>
                   </div>
                 </FormControl>
                 <FormMessage />
               </FormItem>
             )}
           />
         </div>
         <Table>
           <TableCaption>
             A list of styles for correlating sub-category
           </TableCaption>
           <TableHeader>
             <TableRow>
               <TableHead className="text-black">Styles</TableHead>
             </TableRow>
           </TableHeader>
           <TableBody>
             {saveStyle.map((styles, index) => (
               <TableRow key={index}>
                 <TableCell>{styles.name}</TableCell>
                 ...
                 {*/Modals for editing and deleting style/*}
               </TableRow>
             ))}
           </TableBody>
         </Table>
         <Separator />
         <Button disabled={loading} className="ml-auto" type="submit">
           {action}
         </Button>
       </form>
     </Form>
   </>
 );
};


export default SubCategoryForm;
```

**2. API Routes:**

`app/api/[store_id]/sub-categories/[subcategory_id]/route.ts`:

```
export async function GET (
   req: Request,
   { params } : { params: { subcategory_id: string } }
) {
   try {
       if (!params.subcategory_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Sub-Category ID Required", { status : 400})
       }


       const subCategory = await prismadb.subCategory.findUnique({
           where: {
               id: params.subcategory_id,
           },
           include: {
               styles: true,
           },
       });


       return NextResponse.json(subCategory)
      
   } catch (error) {
       console.log('[SUB_CATEGORY_GET]', error);
       return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
   }
}


export async function PATCH (
   req: Request,
   { params } : { params: { store_id: string , subcategory_id: string} }
) {
   try {
       const { userId } = auth();
       const body = await req.json();
       const { name, category_id, styles } = body


       if (!userId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status : 403})
       }
       if (!name) {
           return new NextResponse("Name Required", { status : 400})
       }
       if (!category_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Category ID Required", { status : 400})
       }
       if (!params.subcategory_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Sub-Category ID Required", { status : 400})
       }


       const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
           where: {
               id: params.store_id,
               userId
           }
       })


       if (!storeByUserId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthorised", { status: 403 })
       }


       const subCategory = await prismadb.subCategory.updateMany({
           where: {
               id: params.subcategory_id,
           },
           data: {
               name,
               category_id,
               styles: {
                   updateMany: {
                       data: styles.map((style: string) => ({ name: style })),
                   },
               },
             },
             include: {
               styles: true,
             },
       })


       return NextResponse.json(subCategory)


   } catch (error) {
       console.log('[SUB_CATEGORY_PATCH]', error);
       return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
   }
}


export async function DELETE (
   req: Request,
   { params } : { params: { store_id: string, subcategory_id: string } }
) {
   try {
       const { userId } = auth();


       if (!userId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status : 401 })
       }
       if (!params.subcategory_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Sub-Category ID Required", { status : 400})
       }


       const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
           where: {
               id: params.store_id,
               userId
           }
       })


       if (!storeByUserId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthorised", { status: 403 })
       }


       const subCategory = await prismadb.subCategory.deleteMany({
           where: {
               id: params.subcategory_id,
           }
       });


       return NextResponse.json(subCategory)
      
   } catch (error) {
       console.log('[SUB_CATEGORY_DELETE]', error);
       return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
   }
}
```

`app/api/[store_id]/sub-categories/route.ts`:

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


export async function POST(
   req: Request,
   { params } : { params: { store_id: string } }
) {
   try {


       const body = await req.json()
       const { userId } = auth();
       const { name, category_id, styles } = body
      


       if (!userId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status: 401 })
       }


       if (!name) {
           return new NextResponse("name Required", { status: 400 })
       }


       if (!category_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Category ID Required", { status: 400 })
       }
       if (!styles) {
           return new NextResponse("Styles are Required", { status: 400 })
       }


       if (!params.store_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Store ID Required", { status: 400 })
       }


       const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
           where: {
               id: params.store_id,
               userId
           }
       })


       if (!storeByUserId) {
           return new NextResponse("Unauthorised", { status: 403 })
       }


       const subCategory = await prismadb.subCategory.create({
           data: {
               name: name,
               store_id: params.store_id,
               category_id: category_id,
               styles: {
                   createMany: {
                       data: styles.map((style: string) => ({ name: style })),
                   }
               },
           },
           include: {
             styles: true,
           },
       });


       return NextResponse.json(subCategory);


   } catch(error) {
       console.log("SUB_CATEGORIES_POST", error);
       return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 })
   }
}
export async function GET(
   req: Request,
   { params } : { params: { store_id: string } }
) {
   try {


       if (!params.store_id) {
           return new NextResponse("Store ID Required", { status: 400 })
       }


       const subCategories = await prismadb.subCategory.findMany({
           where: {
               store_id: params.store_id
           }
       });


       return NextResponse.json(subCategories);


   } catch(error) {
       console.log("SUB_CATEGORIES_GET", error);
       return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 })
   }
}
```

**3. Prisma Modals:**

```
model Store {
 id             String        @id @default(uuid())
 name           String
 userId         String
 createdAt      DateTime      @default(now())
 updatedAt      DateTime      @updatedAt
 categories     Category[]    @relation("StoreToCategory")
 sub_categories SubCategory[] @relation("StoreToSubCategory")
 styles         Style[]       @relation("StoreToStyle")
}


model Category {
 id             String        @id @default(uuid())
 store_id       String
 billboard_id   String
 name           String
 createdAt      DateTime      @default(now())
 updatedAt      DateTime      @updatedAt
 store          Store         @relation("StoreToCategory", fields: [store_id], references: [id])
 billboard      Billboard     @relation(fields: [billboard_id], references: [id])
 products       Product[]     @relation("CategoryToProduct")
 sub_categories SubCategory[] @relation("CategoryToSubCategory")


 @@index([store_id])
 @@index([billboard_id])
}


model SubCategory {
 id          String    @id @default(uuid())
 name        String
 createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
 updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt
 store_id    String
 category_id String
 category    Category  @relation("CategoryToSubCategory", fields: [category_id], references: [id])
 store       Store     @relation("StoreToSubCategory", fields: [store_id], references: [id])
 products    Product[] @relation("SubCategoryToProduct")
 styles      Style[]   @relation("SubCategoryToStyles")


 @@index([store_id])
 @@index([category_id])
}


model Style {
 id             String      @id @default(uuid())
 name           String
 createdAt      DateTime    @default(now())
 updatedAt      DateTime    @updatedAt
 store_id       String
 subcategory_id String
 subcategory    SubCategory @relation("SubCategoryToStyles", fields: [subcategory_id], references: [id])
 store          Store       @relation("StoreToStyle", fields: [store_id], references: [id])
 products       Product[]   @relation("StyleToProduct")


 @@index([subcategory_id])
 @@index([store_id])
}
```

**More Info:**

- I've reviewed the TypeScript type definitions and ensured they align with the actual Prisma schema.
- The issue seems to persist despite making various adjustments to the code and troubleshooting steps.

If anyone has encountered similar issues or has expertise in debugging form submission problems, I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions. Any guidance or advice on how to resolve this issue would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'styles' does
> not exist in type

i think you meant to use `style` in form you have

```
    <FormField
         control={form.control}
         name="style"
         render={({ field }) => (...)
```

but when you are destructuring

```
const { name, category_id, styles } = body
```

u r using `styles`

Comment: style has been destructured in the onSubmit function with styles being added as part of the data